# Issues with creating a full back up in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently trying to create a script that will perform a full back up of a directory in bash. After doing research I came up with this:

```
% rsync -r /files/stephen /files/backup
```

I am curious to know if there is a more efficient way to write this or if I am even on the right path.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange! Please [update your post with more context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/455010/edit). What is the issue that you are experiencing? `rsync` is an excellent tool for backing up files.

Comment: `-a` would be better than `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` is usually the right answer, and you are using it correctly.

`-a` does a more complete backup than `-r`

and `-axHAX` even more, but whay level of complexity is needed depends on how ordinary the files are.